# Different result of `sencha app build` and `sencha app watch` command in sencha-cmd

Tags: sencha-cmd, extjs6

I'm using Extjs-6. I created an app using `sencha -sdk D:\xampp\htdocs\Lib\ext-premium-6.0.0\ext-6.0.0 generate app Prj1 D:\xampp\htdocs\ExtProjects\Workspace1\Prj1`. I build the project with `sencha app build` and the theme result is as follow:
[image]
But When I build the project using `sencha app watch` the them result is as follow:
[image]

**Why results are different**?

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any change in theme...For every two time you end up with `new ExtJS 6 default Triton theme`..

If you need to change theme then this is done by changing the extend property in “packages/local/my-classic-theme/package.json” from its default value as shown here:

```
"extend": "theme-neptune"
```

to

```
"extend": "theme-crisp"
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

There is a **bug** related to `sencha app build` and `sencha app watch`.
You can see it at [this thread at Sencha's Forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?316105-Sencha-app-build-does-not-set-LoadOrder-options-in-classic.json&p=1144321)

OLD ANSWER:

For me it seems `sencha app build` does not update classic.json, so you have to execute `sencha app watch`.

I performed the following:

```
$ sencha app build development
Sencha Cmd v6.1.2.15
[INF] Using GPL version of Ext JS version 6.0.1.250 from /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/ext.
[INF] The implications of using GPL version can be found here (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing).
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : classic
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Appending content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/classic.json
[INF] merging 258 input resources into /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/build/development/GoraExplorer/classic/resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/build/development/GoraExplorer/classic/resources
[INF] merging 21 input resources into /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/build/development/GoraExplorer
[INF] merged 0 resources into /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/build/development/GoraExplorer
[INF] Writing content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/sass/example/bootstrap.json
[INF] Writing content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/sass/example/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/classic.json

$ cd ..
$ cp -R webapp /tmp/webapp-build

$ sencha app watch
Sencha Cmd v6.1.2.15
[INF] Using GPL version of Ext JS version 6.0.1.250 from /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/ext.
[INF] The implications of using GPL version can be found here (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing).
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : classic
[INF] Starting server on port : 1841
[INF] Mapping http://localhost:1841/~cmd to /home/alfonso/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.1.2.15...
[INF] Mapping http://localhost:1841/ to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp...
[INF] Application available at http://localhost:1841
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Appending content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/classic.json
[INF] merging 258 input resources into /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/build/development/GoraExplorer/classic/resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/build/development/GoraExplorer/classic/resources
[INF] merging 21 input resources into /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/build/development/GoraExplorer
[INF] merged 0 resources into /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/build/development/GoraExplorer
[INF] Writing content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/sass/example/bootstrap.json
[INF] Writing content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/sass/example/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to /home/alfonso/git/goraexplorer/src/main/webapp/classic.json
[INF] Waiting for changes...
^C

$ cd ..
$ cp -R webapp /tmp/webapp-watch

$ diff -q -r /tmp/webapp-build /tmp/webapp-watch
Los archivos webapp-build/classic.json y webapp-watch/classic.json son distintos
```

(`classic.json` changed)

Here is the diff. As you can see, `sencha app watch` defines a "loadOrder" key that much probably is what makes the difference in your application:

[image]

You can check with the developer tools of the browser (F12) if it shows any error loading files.
Beware that if you execute `sencha app build` again, the changes in `classic.json` will be written wrongly again.

The real problem must be somewhere in the loader, but I think we can't fix it :/